# How to post user id in two different site using curl

Tags: php

I want to post user id via curl init on two url one is `site1/hcomments.php` and other that I want to add is `site2/hcomments.php`

```
$ch = curl_init('https://site1/hcomments.php'); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "id=$postid");
$hasil = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
if (strpos($hasil,'GAGAL') !== false) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("INFO: Somethings was wrong \n :: \n HINTS: \n :: \n [+] Make Sure you was entering a Valid PostID \n [+] Your Post Must Be PUBLIC \n :: \n Please retry your request later.");</script>';
}else{
}
```

Is this possible r not if not than any other way to do this without opening that file?

Comment: Does this work when you post to one of the sites?

Comment: Yes the main file which is hcomments.php is on the same server and this is working fine but I want to post on two url

Comment: 2nd url is on another hosting

Comment: Oh and what does _without opening that file_ mean

Comment: Do you have to be logged in to post on the other site?

Comment: I mean I run this curl to transfer user id without loading any another page on screen

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but this should work

```
$ch = curl_init('https://flexy.tk/hcomments.php'); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "id=$postid");
$hasil = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

$ch1 = curl_init('https://othersite/hcomments.php'); 
curl_setopt ($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch1, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "id=$postid");
$hasil1 = curl_exec ($ch1);
curl_close ($ch1);
```

Comment: You will get 2 results you can check hasil and hasil1.